# Is there a way to fetch and update release pipelines from Azure DevOps using .NET SDK?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Below is the reference to use SDK to fetch and update the Build pipelines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.webapi.buildhttpclient?view=azure-devops-dotnet

Similar to above, do we have any SDK to fetch and update release pipelines as well?

Comment: You could use a rest API call written in C# to fetch an update a release pipeline from the Azure DevOps api. For example you can get a release using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: @GeralexGR, thank you for the response and pointer given.
I am looking for SDK if any to avoid coding from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It took me awhile to sift through the docs, but there is a `ReleaseHttpClient` in the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi.Clients` namespace.

Using that client, you have access to the `GetReleaseDefinitionAsync` and `UpdateReleaseDefinitionAsync` methods.

Package is located here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Release.Client/